# Semantic UI React : How to move Button from Left to Right

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I am using semantic UI React . I included semantic UI React Button but default it showing in Left , I want to show it in Right . Someone please help me how I can move semantic button to right .

[image]

```
<Button.Group>
<Button>Cancel</Button>
<Button.Or />
<Button positive>Save</Button>
```

Comment: So you want to let the whole button group appear on the right side? Or do you want to switch the labels? Or want to have green on the left and grey on the right?

Comment: @grenzbotin Thank You for your comment . Actually I want to move whole button group to right .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The beautiful one solution is just to add `floated="right"` to your Button.Group like that:

```
<Button.Group floated="right">
    <Button>Cancel</Button>
    <Button.Or />
    <Button positive>Save</Button>
</Button.Group>
```

[image]

You can also check this: https://codesandbox.io/s/n0wzzxxl0m

All the options for Button.Group are provided here: https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/button/

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve that via wrapping the button group in a container that will align its children to the right via css.

css:

```
.rightAlign {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: right;
}
```

Button component in wrapping container:

```
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "semantic-ui-react";

const MyButtons = () => {
  return (
    <div className="rightAlign">
      <Button.Group>
        <Button>Cancel</Button>
        <Button.Or />
        <Button positive>Save</Button>
      </Button.Group>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyButtons;
```

See it working here: https://codesandbox.io/s/3yqy09k35m?fontsize=14

Comment: Make sure that the css file in which you defined the class ( in this case ".rightAlign", but you can name the class however you want) is imported in the file you use it. Means - if you you want to have an own css file for your Button component, import the css file. (You can see that I defined the .rightAlign class in the styles.css that got imported in the index.js in codesandbox.)

Comment: Actually I am implementing it through `styled-component` but nothing happen

Comment: I updated the codesandbox with a working container built with styed-components. https://codesandbox.io/s/3yqy09k35m?fontsize=14

Comment: Thank You so much for your comment , Problem was solved ! .